# An unknown Java syntax

Tags: java

Let's see the following code snippet in Java.

```
package common;

final public class Main
{
    private static void show(Object... args)    //<--Here it is...
    {
        for(int i=0;i<args.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(args[i]);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        show(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
    }
}
```

---

The above code in Java works well and displays numbers starting from 1 to 9 through the only loop on the console. The only question here is the meaning of `(Object... args)` in the above code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The three-dot notation is the syntax for variable number of arguments, take a look [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html).

Answer (score 2):

You're using Java's `varargs` notation, which allows the final argument to be passed as either an array or sequence of arguments (of indeterminate length). In your case, you're passing them as a sequence of args:

```
show(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
```

...but you could also pass them like this:

```
show(new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9});
```

Without support for this feature, you'd either have needed to accept an array in the method signature (and always passed the inputs in an array) or specified a fixed number of `int` arguments.